# .htacess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

This may seem like a basic question, but I am not getting how to do it. Here is the Urls below.

> Old Url : http://domain.com/index.php/items/view/item_name
>
> New Url : http://domain.com/index.php/items/details/name/item_name

How do I do a permanent redirect with this set of old and new Urls in htaccess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this code in your DOCUMENT_ROOT's .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(items)/view/(.*)$ /$1/details/name/$2 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: That almost works. But I have a form input with get method and whenever it is submitted, the input text gets appended to the current url. I wonder if that is because of htaccess or my url configuration (it's a Yii application.) url gets appended only on form submission, clicking on other link works fine.

Comment: Not aware of Yii URL rewriting logic but an you tell me little more technical details, like what does final URL look like after form submission? And what problem it is causing?

Comment: It just appends the controller action url to the current url. Let's say I am currently on the page http://domain/item/color/black and submit the form. So, instead of getting an url like http://domain/search/terms I get an url like http://domain/item/color/black/search/terms. I did some search and looks like its an issue with how Yii UrlManager handles the GET method. I am not able to find a solution to this though and I am now wondering whether it will be good to just POST the param and redirect it to the fucntion.

Comment: The reason why it is happening because Form's action is a relative URI i.e. `"search/items"`. If you can make your form's action as `"/search/items"` then this problem can be fixed.

Comment: Yes. It's all sorted out now. Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me....

upload a .htaccess file to the folder where ur file exists with the following data (it should be on a new line in the htaccess file)

```
redirect 301 /some_dir/oldpage.htm http://www.newdomain.com/newpage.htm
```

and from what i read somewhere when you need to do the same for a dynamic page you can use the following

consider the page as

```
http://www.example.com/page.php?id=13
```

the redirect would be

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=13$
RewriteRule ^/page.php$ http://www.example.com/newname.htm? [L,R=301]
```

here is what i got on googling for this 
http://www.tamingthebeast.net/articles3/spiders-301-redirect.htm